# Why isn't this JSON format valid?

Tags: json

Why isn't this format invalid? I need to two levels of embedding.

```
{
     "userId": "008", 
  {
    "sku": "6157068",
    "inputText":"what's that?"
  } 
}
```

Comment: How did you plan to access that data?

Comment: Is not valid or is not invalid?

Comment: every nested object must have a key for access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is because you declare "anonymous" nested object who are not allowed.

```
{
  "userId": "008", 
  "message": {
    "sku": "6157068",
    "inputText":"what's that?"
  } 
}
```

Add key who looks like this will fix your issue.

or if you nested object is array, this should be like this :

```
{
    "userId": "008",
    "messages": [
        {
            "sku": "6157068",
            "inputText": "what's that?"
        },
        {
            "sku": "6157069",
            "inputText": "Is valid json dude"               
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, JSON is a data format which is written in key /value pairs..
Details:

JSON objects are surrounded by curly braces {}.

JSON objects are written in key/value pairs.

Keys must be strings, and values must be a valid JSON data type (string, number, object, array, boolean or null).

Keys and values are separated by a colon.

Each key/value pair is separated by a comma.